# Netbeans 6.1 Debugger stopped working with error com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Unexpected JDWP Error: 502

Tags: exception, netbeans, debugging

I have been using Netbeans 6.1 for a long time and my debugger has always been flawless.  Somehow recently (within the last two weeks or so) my debugger stops at breakpoints but it either freezes most of the time or i can't find out the value of any variable, my local variables wont expand and my watches will sometimes show all nulls even for this.hashCode() or not even update at all and freeze.

When this happens i see the following netbeans exceptions

```
com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Unexpected JDWP Error: 502
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.JDWPException.toJDIException(JDWPException.java:47)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.ObjectReferenceImpl.invokeMethod(ObjectReferenceImpl.java:379)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.expr.TreeEvaluator.invokeVirtual(TreeEvaluator.java:164)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.JPDADebuggerImpl.invokeMethod(JPDADebuggerImpl.java:844)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.models.AbstractObjectVariable.invokeMethod(AbstractObjectVariable.java:417)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ui.models.JavaVariablesFilter.getChildren(JavaVariablesFilter.java:133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ui.models.VariablesTreeModelFilter.getChildren(VariablesTreeModelFilter.java:193)
    at org.netbeans.spi.viewmodel.Models$CompoundTreeModel.getChildren(Models.java:628)
    at org.netbeans.spi.viewmodel.Models$CompoundModel.getChildren(Models.java:2819)
    at org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode$TreeModelChildren.evaluateLazily(TreeModelNode.java:701)
    at org.netbeans.modules.viewmodel.TreeModelNode$LazyEvaluator.run(TreeModelNode.java:1124)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:561)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:986)




com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Unexpected JDWP Error: 502
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.JDWPException.toJDIException(JDWPException.java:47)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.ObjectReferenceImpl.invokeMethod(ObjectReferenceImpl.java:379)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.expr.TreeEvaluator.invokeVirtual(TreeEvaluator.java:164)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.JPDADebuggerImpl.invokeMethod(JPDADebuggerImpl.java:844)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.models.AbstractObjectVariable.getToStringValue(AbstractObjectVariable.java:315)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.models.AbstractObjectVariable.getToStringValue(AbstractObjectVariable.java:285)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ui.models.VariablesNodeModel.getLimitedToString(VariablesNodeModel.java:316)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ui.models.VariablesNodeModel.getShortDescriptionSynch(VariablesNodeModel.java:275)
    at org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ui.models.VariablesNodeModel$1.run(VariablesNodeModel.java:233)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:561)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:986)
```

Does anybody know how to fix or workaround this problem?  I have googled this exception but can't find anything of value.  The only thing i found is about running two different JVMs, one to debug and one to run the application (but this is not the case for me, both JVMs are the exact same version "1.4.2_03").  I am running into this issue at work so upgrading Java or my IDE is not an option, though it this was fixed in a newer version of the IDE i would still like to know that but most importantly I really need a fix or workaround for this.  I have also not changed any settings in my project or NetBeans that i am aware of from the time my debugger was working to now.

Thanks

Append:  I also got the following message
A com.sun.jdi.InternalException exception has occurred.
Please report this at http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html,
including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment.
The messages.log file is located in your C:\Documents and Settings\default.netbeans\6.1\var\log folder.

And i have a copy of messages.log if anyone wants me to post it.

I also tried debugging with a different project that i haven't used in a while and it still failed in the same way.

I could really use some help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably [issue # 136461](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=136461). If the software update(s) for 6.1 do not fix it, then you're probably out of luck. NB 6.1 is over 2 years old at this point.

I understand the desire to keep all developers on the same IDE release. A change to a .form file or a nbproject file can spoil an unwary developer's day.

However, can you install a personal copy of 6.9 and just use it for debugging? Keep the 6.1 around to verify everything before committing.

Comment: The update fixed it and i got our development team to upgrade.  Sorry for the late post.